# r cran - add one row to a data frame in each loop

Tags: r, loops

I have 2 tables:

```
> series
  rutcli X3 X5 X12 X15 X20 X28    1
1      1  1  1   0   2   0   1 <NA>
2      2  0  0   1   1   1   2 dias

> final
              1    2    3   4  5  6  7
2          dias    0    0  12 15 20 28
21 repeticiones    0    0   1  1  1  2
3         orden <NA> <NA> 100 83 71 88
```

I need to add the 3rd row of final to series
I tried:

```
series[1,(ncol(series)+1):(ncol(series)+1+ncol(final)) ] <-final[3,]
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Since this is inside a loop that goes through each line of series I need to add up only one row at each time.

Comment: `series[1, ...] <- ...` will replace the first row, not add an additional row. Without seeing your code, I would suggest using `rbind` instead possibly

Comment: First of all, adding a row at a time to a data.frame is generally an inefficient and poor way to build a data.frame. Perhaps you could step back and show your input and desired output. There may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Gaby P If you are using  rbind make sure you have the same colnames for data.frame and also make sure that there are no factor columns or else need to change the levels.